# Google Play Billing (v5): How to let the user upgrade from a subscription to an IAP

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

Lets say I have two products:

- **subscription**: auto-renewing yearly
- **in-app purchase**: non-consumable lifetime purchase

Is there any way to upgrade from the subscription to the IAP without forcing the user to manually cancel the subscription?

There is `SubscriptionUpdateParams` with `setOldPurchaseToken`, but it seems this can only be used to upgrade from one subscription base-plan to another (e.g. monthly to yearly). The documentation only says:

> Specifies the Google Play Billing purchase token that the user is upgrading or downgrading from.

Is there any good way to do this kind of flow?